# How To Enable JsonView With Micronaut

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, micronaut, json-view

I've got the latest version of Micronaut as of this question (1.1.0) and see that support for the @JsonView jackson annotation has been added. However, when I add it to my controller and enable it in my application.yml, I do not see the annotation being applied to the response, I still receive the full object. Note: I am using Lombok as well with my POJO's, and I don't know if that's interfering.

Controller:

```
@Controller("/v1")
public class Controller {

private MongoClient client;

public Controller(MongoClient mongoClient) {
    this.client = mongoClient;
}

@Get("/ids")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@JsonView(Views.IdOnly.class)
public Single<List<Grain>> getIdsByClientId(@QueryValue(value = "clientId") String clientId) {
    return Flowable.fromPublisher(getCollection().find(Filters.eq("data.clientId", clientId))).toList();
}

private MongoCollection<Grain> getCollection() {
    CodecRegistry grainRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(MongoClients.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
    return client
            .getDatabase("db").withCodecRegistry(grainRegistry)
            .getCollection("col", Data.class);
}
```

}

Data:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Data {

    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    @JsonView(Views.IdOnly.class)
    private ObjectId id;

    private boolean active = true;

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private DataMeta dataMeta;

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private DataContent dataContent;

}
```

View:

```
public class Views {

    public static class IdOnly {
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
---
micronaut:
  application:
    name: mojave-query-api

---
mongodb:
  uri: "mongodb://${MONGO_USER:user}:${MONGO_PASSWORD:password}@${MONGO_HOST:localhost}:${MONGO_PORT:27017}/db?ssl=false&authSource=db"

---
jackson.json-view.enabled: true
```

application.yml (alternate version also didn't work)

```
---
micronaut:
  application:
    name: mojave-query-api

---
mongodb:
  uri: "mongodb://${MONGO_USER:user}:${MONGO_PASSWORD:password}@${MONGO_HOST:localhost}:${MONGO_PORT:27017}/db?ssl=false&authSource=db"

---
jackson:
  json-view:
    enabled: true
```

I'm not sure if I have the jackson line in the wrong place in the application.yml file or if the feature isn't working as intended, or something totally different that I'm missing? Input appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last version application.yml is correct, but you forget to mark your Data class as @JsonView class, so the working version is

```
@Data
@JsonView
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Data {

    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    @JsonView(Views.IdOnly.class)
    private ObjectId id;

    private boolean active = true;

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private DataMeta dataMeta;

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private DataContent dataContent;

}
```

Comment: Interesting, hand't even thought about needing it there! Thank you!